# When Service Account should be used to access google api?

Tags: google-api, gmail, google-oauth, gmail-api, service-accounts

I am trying to use google api for getting new emails from gmail account. However reading the docs I found that there are two types to access api the first one without authorization (with json credential) and second one one is Service Account (with p12 certificate and secretkey)

Can not understand what the difference between this access? What exactly should I use?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Oauth2](http://www.daimto.com/google-developer-console-oauth2/) is the first type you are looking at.   With Oauth2 a consent screen is displayed to the user who must approve your access.  Usage you want to access a users Gmail account, you want to access a users google calendar, you want to access a users google drive.

With a [service account](http://www.daimto.com/google-developer-console-service-account/) access is pre-authorized by taking the service account email address and adding it as a user for data in question.  Usage:  You want to allow other users to upload files to your google drive account, you would add the service account email address to a folder on google drive then the service account will be able to upload to that folder with out having to prompt any user for permissions.

Use Oauth2 when you want to access a users account,  use a service account when you want to access an account controlled by you the developer.

If you want to access a users Gmail account you need to use Oauth2 you cant grant another user access to your Gmail so there is no way to give a service account access to it.

Comment: Thanks. So main difference is that I will see popup with suggestion to make authorization in first variant and second variant already contains authorization. Right?

Comment: yup . I like to think of service accounts as per authorized.  You already gave the permissions when you set up the service account.   Adding the service account email address as a user on a google calendar for example gives it access to the calendar.    If its a user you have to pop up the auth window and ask them can I see your data.  check out my beginner google development series.  might help http://www.daimto.com/google-development-beginners/

Comment: @DaImTo thank you for your answer: do you know if there are any limitations to using a service account?

Comment: Non assuming you have access to preautorise the service account.